# How do I insert a photo into the database?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have a problem inserting the blob type photo in the database. I wrote the code, I tried to test it with Postman but I see that nothing happens, that is, the photo is not inserted in the database.
I specify that I do not get any errors.
This is the code:

Product.java

```
package Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import Model.Product;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String prodcode; 
    private String name; 
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] photo;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String prodcode, String name, byte[] photo) {
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getProdcode() {
        return prodcode;
    }

    public void setProdcode(String prodcode) {
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

Product_DAO_Imp

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.Model.*;

@Repository
public class Product_DAO_Imp  implements Product_DAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    
    @Override   
     public boolean updatePhoto(byte[] photo, String prodcode) {  
        boolean status = false;
        Session currentSession= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();  
          
        try  
        {  
            Query<Product> query = currentSession.createQuery("update Product set photo = :photo where prodcode=:prodcode ");  
            query.setParameter("photo", photo);  
            query.setParameter("prodcode", prodcode);  
            status=true; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Product_Service_Imp

```
package com.example.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.example.DAO.Product_DAO;
import com.example.Model.Product;

@Service
@Transactional
public class Product_Service_Imp implements Product_Service {
 
    @Autowired
    private Product_DAO productdao;
    
    @Override
     public boolean store(MultipartFile file, String prodcode) throws IOException {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
        Product product=new Product();
        byte[] photo=file.getBytes();
        System.out.println(prodcode);
        System.out.println(photo);
        productdao.updatePhoto(photo, prodcode);
        status=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }  
}
```

Controller.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.example.Model.Product;
import com.example.Service.Product_Service;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Product_Service productservice;
    
    @PostMapping("/save-photoproduct/{prodcode}")  
    public boolean handleFileUpload(@PathVariable String prodcode,@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {  
        return productservice.store(file,prodcode);          
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you to store images in DB (blob field). Because when you store image in database, the database size will increase.

The best way is to store only image path in DB (String image_url), and store the image file in a folder in you're system or somewhere else (like AWS S3).

Please see the following examples:

1. [Uploading Files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)
2. [Spring Boot file upload example](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/)
3. [Spring Boot 2 + Angular 11 + Upload File Example](https://frontbackend.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-2-angular-11-upload-file-example)
4. [Angular 11 + SpringBoot Upload/Download MultipartFile](https://grokonez.com/angular-11-springboot-upload-download-multipartfile)

Comment: as I am new I would need a site where I show this together with angular, ie the backend part in Springboot and the Frontend part in Angular. Thank you

Comment: Please see the examples: 3 and 4

Comment: thanks, but I see that the part relating to the display of the image is not present. It is not found on the internet, for me this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to store only URL of the photo in DB column after storing the photo in a file store or object store.

For a while if we assume indeed string photo in the DB as BLOB is required.  Adding some more details may help community members to help identifying reason.

1. is the table already having a record with matching prod code? *zero row match* will return *success* and not an error.
2. a supporting test case and result which can help simulate the scenario or confirm indeed the update statement was executed

Comment: yes exactly, I have already created the table and inserted a couple of records. The prodcode PC001 already exists in the table, I just want to insert the product image in it.
When I try to send the command with Postman, it returns true but the image is not inserted in the db

Comment: See the examples in my answer

Comment: how do i get the test case?